# Unity Type Mismatch For Prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a couple of prefabs with some public variables but when I assign a component to one of them (by clicking at the circle on the right) it says type mismatch however, when I spawn the prefab and assign the component it works.

I tried changing the variable that didn't work by a game object and then use GetComponent to get the component but it said type mismatch again and it only accepted other prefabs.

By the way, the problem started happening when I changed the player's layer

Comment: you should show an example code and classes

Comment: You can't have scene references in assets -> if you close the scene your objects are unloaded and the reference is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far I understand, I would suggest you:

- copy your prefab to hierarchy. then right click on it >> prefab >>unpack completely. Probably now you can assign a component. then create a new prefab from this edited object.

This should work. Lemme know if not works.

Answer (score 0):

Layers has nothing to do with it. You can't assign a scene object to the prefab's object field. When dealing with prefabs, all its object reference fields (with types derived from UnityEngine.Object) could store only other persistent objects like materials, scriptable objects and other prefabs root objects/components (for the sake of instantiation).

So, if you have a prefab with fields which should be populated with the references to a scene objects, you need to do it at runtime using some object manager. The more convenient way to do so is either at the moment of instantiation of the prefab, if those target objects are already existing, or at the moment of the spawn of those target objects, if the prefab instance is already spawned. The concrete implementation is heavily dependent on your architecture and code, which is not covered in question.

Comment: I don't think code is related to this problem

Comment: I edited the answer to be more clear, please read.

Comment: Good to hear that. Please mark the answer as correct :)